# <class 'TypeError'>: LP_c_long instance instead of list

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have this python code:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/serial_communication/crc.so')

C=0
def spi_process(gpio,level,tick):
    print("Detected")
    data = [0]*1024
    with open(output_file_path(), 'w') as f:
        for x in range(1):
            spi.xfer2(data)
            values = struct.unpack("<" +"I"*256, bytes(data))
            C = lib.crc32Word(0xffffffff,data,1024)
            f.write("\n")
            f.write("\n".join([str(x) for x in values]))
        print(C)

input("Press Enter to start the process ")

cb1=pi.callback(INTERRUPT_GPIO, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, spi_process)

while True:
    lib.crc32Word.restype=ctypes.c_int
    lib.crc32Word.argtypes=[ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p), ctypes.c_int]
    time.sleep(1)
```

But when I run it, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_innerself.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1213, in run cb.func(cb.gpio, newLevel, tick)
  File "2crc_spi.py", line 47, in spi_process
    C=lib.crc32Word(0xffffffff,data,1024)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: LP_c_long instance instead of list
```

I am trying to call this C function from a c library:

```
uint32_t crc32Word(uint32_t crc, const void *buffer, uint32_t size)
```

Can someone please help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to the following code.  The 2nd parameter was incorrect as `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)` would be used for C `void**` not `void*`.  The other parameters were using signed vs. unsigned types so that has been corrected as well.  The `data` must be either `bytes` or a `ctypes` array such as `(c_uint8 * 1024)()` to be suitable for `c_void_p`.

```py
lib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/serial_communication/crc.so')
lib.crc32Word.argtypes = ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint32
lib.crc32Word.restype = ctypes.c_uint32

data = bytes([0] * 1024)
crc = lib.crc32Word(0xffffffff, data, len(data))
```

Comment: Hey @MarkTolonen, when I use the bytes method, even though RPi receives data correctly (checked using logic analyzer), it just stores 0s in the file. So I thought of using the ctypes method. with ctypes method `data = (ctypes.c_uint*1024)`, I have 2 problems, first, that it still stores 0s and second that I receive an error saying: `struct.unpack requires a buffer of 1024 bytes`. Can you please help? Or should I post a new question/edit this post? Thanks.

Comment: @Dar Unpack doesn't understand `ctypes` types.  It expects a Python `bytes` buffer or similar object that supports the Python buffer interface.  You'll need a new question since this is a different issue then the titled question.  Make sure to show all relevant code.  `spi.xfer(data)` isn't shown here but it is probably the issue if `data` isn't updated.