# Python bytes buffer only giving out zeros even though data is being correctly received through SPI on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, ctypes

This is a follow up question from: [<class 'TypeError'>: LP_c_long instance instead of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292480/class-typeerror-lp-c-long-instance-instead-of-list/71298738?noredirect=1#comment126036149_71298738) but is a different issue so I am posting a new question here.

I am using ctypes to invoke a c function from python script. The c function which is being invoked is:

```
uint32_t crc32Word(uint32_t crc, const void *buffer, uint32_t size)
```

I have this python code:

```
import datetime
import os
import struct
import time
import pigpio
import spidev
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/serial_communication/crc.so')
lib.crc32Word.argtypes = ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint32
lib.crc32Word.restype = ctypes.c_uint32

bus = 0
device = 0
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(bus, device)
spi.max_speed_hz = 4000000
spi.mode = 0

pi.set_mode(12, pigpio.INPUT)

C=0
 
def output_file_path():
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
               datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%dT%H.%M.%S") + ".csv")
 
def spi_process(gpio,level,tick):
    print("Detected")
    data = bytes([0]*1024)
    spi.xfer([0x02])
    with open(output_file_path(), 'w') as f:
        t1=datetime.datetime.now()
        for x in range(1):
            spi.xfer2(data)
            values = struct.unpack("<" +"I"*256, bytes(data))
            C = lib.crc32Word(0xffffffff,data,len(data))
            f.write("\n")
            f.write("\n".join([str(x) for x in values]))
        t2=datetime.datetime.now()
        print(t2-t1)
        print(C)

input("Press Enter to start the process ")
spi.xfer2([0x01])

cb1=pi.callback(INTERRUPT_GPIO, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, spi_process)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Previously, I initialized data as `data = [0]*1024`, so I was receiving some error as mentioned in the previous post. But the error was resolved by initializing data to bytes. Now the issue that I have is even though the correct data is received on Raspberry Pi (checked using logic analyzer), only 0s are stored in the file.

I also tried initializing data as arrays instead of lists using numpy library as below, but I receive an error saying:
Tried code:

```
import numpy as np
 
#changed initialization of data to:
data= np.arange(1024) #also tried: np.zeros(1024,ctypes.c_uint8), also get same error
```

Error:

```
File "2crc_spi.py", line 48, in spi_process
   spi.xfer2(data)
TypeError: Non-Int/Long value in arguments: b5410b00
```

But data only receives a byte at a time so not sure where is the issue when using array.

Can someone please help? Thanks~

EDIT:
Below is the original code that was working fine with the data collection and unpacking functions before I started integrating the CRC functionality:

```
import datetime
import os
import struct
import time
import pigpio
import spidev

bus = 0
device = 0
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(bus, device)
spi.max_speed_hz = 4000000
spi.mode = 0

pi.set_mode(12, pigpio.INPUT)

a=0
 
def output_file_path():
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
               datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%dT%H.%M.%S") + ".csv")
 
def spi_process(gpio,level,tick):
    print("Detected")
    data = [0]*2048
    spi.xfer([0x02])
    with open(output_file_path(), 'w') as f:
        t1=datetime.datetime.now()
        for x in range(1):
            spi.xfer2(data)
            values = struct.unpack("<" +"I"*256, bytes(data))
            f.write("\n")
            f.write("\n".join([str(x) for x in values]))
        t2=datetime.datetime.now()
        print(t2-t1)

input("Press Enter to start the process ")
spi.xfer2([0x01])

cb1=pi.callback(INTERRUPT_GPIO, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, spi_process)

while True:
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `data` itself is an immutable string.  Not familiar with the RPi libraries, but a quick [google search](https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/dnld/draft_spidev_doc.pdf) shows `spi.xfer2()` returns received data, e.g. `recv = spi.xfer2(to_send)`.  `values` is just unpacking the data sent (all zeros).

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I don't understand if data is an immutable string, how does it affect? Can you please explain? And yes, `xfer()` returns received data. But `values` is the result after unpacking the `data` that is received, not sent. Unpack integrates together 4 bytes (or 4 `data` values) to form a word (32-bits). This code works as expected when I did not integrate the CRC functionality.

Comment: `immutable` means `read-only`.  The *return value* of `spi.xfer2` is the received data.  You need to assign the received data to a variable and unpack *that*, so not `spi.xfer2(data)` but `recv = spi.xfer2(data)`.  `data` is unchanged.  I'm not familiar with RPi just reading the docs so give it a try.

Comment: Are you saying regarding the part where I used array instead of lists? I tried doing what you suggested and passed `recv` to the unpack function instead of `data` but I still receive the same error: `...Non-Int/Long value in arguments: b538fb00` but with different value. Also, I want to clarify that before I changed the initialization of `data`, I was still directly passing `data` to the unpack function and it was working fine. Here I think the processor doesn't even reach the unpack function but gives error before that.

Comment: Again I'm no RPi expert, `data = bytes([0] * 1024)` was working for you, and the docs I read say the return value is the result, which makes sense...a function can't alter an immutable parameter of type bytes.  I don't have a setup to run your code just giving advice.  Perhaps show the code that was "working fine" before the change for comparison.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I have added the original code in the question that was working fine before I integrated this CRC functionality.

Comment: In the older code `data =[0]*2048` is a mutable list, not an immutable bytes object.  So **IF** `spi.xfer2(data)` modifies the data in the list I could see this working.  But you should convert the data to bytes permanently before calling unpack, e.g. `data = bytes(data)` so it will work with unpack *and* the crc function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark's suggested in comments, you would have to store the *data* into another variable/list, for example: `recv = spi.xfer2(data)`. Then you would need to use this *recv* in your *unpack* function.
Further, you could also use a python library called *zlib* instead of using a c library (there are other python libraries as well).

Another point, since *zlib* takes only bytes as input, you would need to convert *recv* into bytes (here *recv* is a list; check my code).
I modified some of your code.

```
import datetime
import os
import struct
import time
import pigpio
import spidev
import zlib

bus = 0
device = 0
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(bus, device)
spi.max_speed_hz = 4000000
spi.mode = 0

pi.set_mode(12, pigpio.INPUT)

C=0
 
def output_file_path():
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
               datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%dT%H.%M.%S") + ".csv")
 
def spi_process(gpio,level,tick):
    print("Detected")
    data = bytes([0]*1024)
    spi.xfer2([0x02])
    with open(output_file_path(), 'w') as f:
        t1=datetime.datetime.now()
        for x in range(1):
            recv = spi.xfer2(data)
            values = struct.unpack("<" +"I"*256, bytes(recv))
            C = zlib.crc32(bytes(recv))
            f.write("\n")
            f.write("\n".join([str(x) for x in values]))
        t2=datetime.datetime.now()
        print(t2-t1)
        print(C)

input("Press Enter to start the process ")
spi.xfer2([0x01])

cb1=pi.callback(INTERRUPT_GPIO, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, spi_process)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```